# calendar in fullcalendar is not showing

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

I have a blade `calendar.blade.php`, where I'm showing the events. I got it working on 8/23/2018, but now it's gone, even in the older copy of the program. it's not showing anything. am I missing something? or added something? [It's only showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3PpD.png). I hope you can help me with this. Here's my code:

```
    <!-- calendar.blade.php -->
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('Admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    @if (\Session::has('success'))
          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ \Session::get('success') }}</p>
          </div><br />
         @endif
       <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h2>Schedules</h2>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body" >


                <div id='calendar'></div>

                <!-- <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}}"></script>
                <script src="{{asset('js/moment.min.js')}}"></script>
                <script src="{{asset('js/fullcalendar.min.js')}}"></script> -->

              <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>



                <script>

                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                      events:[
                      @foreach($events as $event)
                      {
                        title: '{{$event->pxID}}',
                        start: '{{$event->vacSchedule}}',
                        url: "{{url('doctor/details',$event->id)}}"
                      },
                      @endforeach
                      ]
                    })
                  });
                </script>

            </div>

        </div>
        <a href="{{url('doctor/home')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Any js error messages in the dev console?

Comment: Also, why fullcalendar v2.2.7? That came out in Feb 2015.

Comment: you've got the CSS for fullCalendar 3.1, but the code for 2.2.7. This is highly likely to cause issues. Make sure your versions match. As mentioned above I would suggest using a newer version - the latest is 3.9

Comment: @ourmandave yah there were errors, it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined". I tried to manually input the events and it worked.

Comment: that error means you probably have events with missing and/or invalid start or end dates. Please pay attention also to what I wrote above regarding versioning.

Comment: @ADyson yah. fixed it. thank you. I just change the version and the css. Thank you